# Safari iframe cookie issues

Tags: javascript, cookies, iframe, safari

My client's site (siteA.com) displays a form from a remote service (forms.siteB.com). The form loads correctly in all browsers except for Safari on iOS and macOS. In Safari, the following cookie notice is displayed: *Your browser is currently set to block cookies. You must change your browser settings to allow cookies before you can complete this form. You may revert your settings when you are done.*

From what I can tell Safari is using ITP and is blocking third party cookies. I have been reading about the Storage Session API (https://webkit.org/blog/8124/introducing-storage-access-api/), but am unsure if it would provide a solution. The form's iframe code includes `sandbox="allow-storage-access-by-user-activation allow-scripts allow-same-origin"`, and I have looked at the following code:

```
<script>
function makeRequestWithUserGesture() {
    var promise = document.requestStorageAccess();
    promise.then(
        function () {
        // Storage access was granted.
        },
        function () {
        // Storage access was denied.
        }
    );
}
</script>
<button onclick="makeRequestWithUserGesture()">Play video</button>
```

I am not sure if this would work with allowing the iframe to load from the third party site. It does work with iframes used to embed Google Doc forms. Does anyone know if Google does something special on their end to enable embedded forms to set cookies across domains?

Answer (score 3):

I've been looking into this problem and the whole thing is awful.

You're right that it won't work, unless you can host the form on a sub-domain (which is unlikely).

You need to visit the form's domain in a new (or the redirect the current) window and set a cookie, so that Safari knows that you've visited the site before. Then you can request the storage access and it'll do a pop-up and you should be ok.

It's an awful experience and, as bad as it is, it's arguably better to have the form just open in a new window and have it filled in there.

Very frustrating, but it seems embedded functionality via iframes are on their way out due to this privacy overkill.

Unless someone can find some more hacks!

Comment: So is it that the requestStorageAccess will never work in an iFrame situation then?

Comment: It does work, but it's just an awkward process for the visitor. For my own project, I ended up doing the work so that my iframed website would respond on a subdomain of the parent site. The customer had to set up the appropriate DNS records. This works without any pop-ups or redirections, but is obviously not possible for many scenarios.